Adding customization in omni supervisor page
I need to add a lightning web component in Omni Supervisor page with the context of EmbeddedMessaging per user. So here can be the options I'm looking for:

Add an action like we currently have "Change Status" and "Monitor", which can open a popup or maybe utility bar item showing lwc OR
add a tab in Chat window, which can show the lwc

I'm open for more suggestions as well if something like that is possible.

